# Reading/Writing only part of a 8-bit register VERILOG

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, verilog

So I have a 8-bit Counter, and it stores 0-255.

**In a nutshell, in case my explanation isn't sufficient. I have a value ABCDEFGH which is composed of 8 bits. Is there a way to read ABCD or EFGH? Also, if I have a new value of ABCD, can I write it into ABCDEFGH without disrupting EFGH?**

So my bus implementation is only 4 bits wide, so I'm splitting up the counter into two 4-bit values that I can read.

My problem is the issue of how to handle a read and write on this.

The solution I can come up with is as follows:
Write 1010 to most significant bits of 8-bit register currently holding 01010101.

Add 1010 to clean 8-bit register to get 00001010. Bit shift it left 4 times to get 10100000, extract the 4 LSB from the original register, and then add it to this value.

My question is:

First, is there a way to read out only 4 bits of an 8-bit register?

Second, is there a more elegant way to handle writes of 4-bit values into 8-bit registers than my very unpolished method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean, just because bits are part of the same named register, each bit is a separate hardware flip-flop.

```
reg [7:0] data;

always @( posedge clk or negedge rst_n ) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    data[3:0] <= 4'b0;
  end
  else begin
    data[3:0] <= 'bx ; //Next LSBs
  end
end

always @( posedge clk or negedge rst_n ) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    data[7:4] <= 4'b0;
  end
  else begin
    data[7:4] <= 'bx ; //Next MSBs
  end
end
```

I would not advise the above.

It feels like your approach to the problem may be a bit different to mine. Have you thought about having 2 4-bit registers and joining them when required?

```
reg  [3:0] data_lsb;
reg  [3:0] data_msb;
wire [3:0] data;

always @( posedge clk or negedge rst_n ) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    data_lsb <= 4'b0;
  end
  else begin
    data_lsb <= 'bx ; //Next LSBs
  end
end

always @( posedge clk or negedge rst_n ) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    data_msb <= 4'b0;
  end
  else begin
    data_msb <= 'bx ; //Next MSBs
  end
end

assign data = {data_msb, data_lsb};
```

Comment: Ah yes, This is exactly what I was looking for. Concatenation and this stuff is coming back now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I under stand correctly, you have an 4-bit input, 4-bit output, and want to store it in the MSB/LSB bits of a 8-bit register. The following example code might be what wot are looking for.

```
module example (
    input clk, rst_n,
    inout write_en,
    input sel_in, sel_out,
    input  [3:0] in,
    output [3:0] out );

  reg [7:0] store;

  always @(posedge clk, negedge rst_n) begin
    if (!rst_n) begin // reset
      store <= 8'h0;
    end
    else begin // input write
      if (write_en) begin
        if (sel_in) store[7:4] <= in;
        else        store[3:0] <= in;
      end
    end
  end

  always @* begin // output read
    if (sel_out) out = store[7:4];
    else         out = store[3:0];
  end

endmodule
```